# Fargate vs Lambda for migrating cron job

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, scheduled-tasks, job-scheduling, aws-fargate

We have a cron job which runs every 4hrs on an 10MB file and completes processing within 20 minutes.
We are migrating it to NAWS using cloud watch events to triggers lambda/fargate.

I am trying to figure out the best option among these three.

1. Lambda with concurrency : We can distribute the input file and run lambdas in parallel.
2. Lambda with daisy chaining : Create different lambda functions for different functionality so that all the components can run in parallel where all the component lambdas are running concurrently as well.
3. Fargate : I don't know much about Fargate except that is a container based platform, and Fargate might be suitable for long-running scheduled tasks which can be migrated to Fargate, with less refactoring required than for migrating to Lambda.

Any suggestions how to choose? And if I should consider any other options as well

Answer (score 4):

Option 3 is a good fit for your use case.  Basically you would write a Docker container to perform the processing, and configure a Cloudwatch event on a cron schedule.  I also use Fargate for this purpose and it works great.

Option 1 sounds OK, but sounds like unnecessary extra steps to split the file up.

Option 2 sounds too complex.

You could also look at AWS Batch, but it might be overkill for this task.

Comment: I'd choose option 3 as well. You can manage the cronjob pods pretty nicely with `kubectl` and you can manually run your crons based on existing cron templates.